# WOPI client and host query

Tags: ms-wopi

Trying to implement Collabora (CODE) editor on a web app. Currently writing the wopi host code, and I am seeking clarity on one minor detail:

Does wopi client (in my case, CODE) access the file directly from my wopi host using the url passed to it and then send the data to user's browser (in case of which, during updating, the data is posted to wopi client which in turn will post to wopi host? right?), or does accessing and updating the file is done from the user's browser through wopi host url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image of a [WOPI-Conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6rQ4.png) may help. The WOPI server (which is the server where the endpoints are), communicates with the WOPI client. The WOPI client then renders the iframe in the user browser. When saving, the WOPI client will POST the new content to the "PutFile" endpoint on the WOPI server to save it.